# Raspberry pi 4B Error looking up passwd struct for uid 1000: Input/output error

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

i´m getting this strange and crash raspbian os error with a frecuency of 1 time every 4 days.
My raspberry pi 4B its always running and of course pluged in, with the original charger, 1 time every five days I reboot it and check for updates, also its running a c# net6 web api , portainer with one postgresSQL container and this would be the why of its always running.

This is the error:
[image]

And nothing works, I mean, you can move the mouse but all other things it throws a different error, I have to unplug it and plug it again to start again.
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I don´t understand you

Comment: Did this get resolved? Having the same issue. Running Bullseye and OpenCPN.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your Pi to external hardware via serial communication? I don't know the answer but I am getting the same error. In my setup a microcontroller communicates with Pi4B via serial posrt. I am using npm serial library on Pi side. Whenever my microcontroller is switched off but Pi is still on, this error shows up and nothing works. Only hard rebooting it seems to be the solution for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).